# Nginx: Rewrite from base domain to a sub directory

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a blog hosted at http://site.com/blog.

How do I instruct nginx to rewrite requests from `site.com` to `site.com/blog`?

This should not be permanent.

Comment: Presuming all URLs and keep the relative path, you should be able to just add `rewrite  ^/(.*)$ /blog/$1 redirect` to the top of your server block.

Comment: @cyberx86 Infinite redirect loop, that.

Comment: Now that was just careless of me - I should know better. Replacing, 'redirect' with 'last' doesn't generate an infinite loop, but still isn't quite ideal (it keeps the URL, but serves the right file).

Comment: solution shared in this link worked for me: <http://serverfault.com/a/677337/386872>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
location = / {
    rewrite ^ http://site.com/blog/ redirect;
}
```

This'll just do requests specifically for the root.  If you need to catch everything (redirect `http://site.com/somearticle/something.html` to `http://site.com/blog/somearticle/something.html`), then you'll need something more involved:

```
location /blog/ {
    # Empty; this is just here to avoid redirecting for this location,
    # though you might already have some config in a block like this.
}
location / {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://site.com/blog/$1 redirect;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

*try this instead:*

```
location = / {
      return 301 /blog/;
 }
```

The key here is **'='** symbol.

Answer (score 1):

This has not worked for me. 
This is what has worked:

1. Open the NGINX configuration file for your site. Inside of the server block, add the path to your root directory and set the priority order for files:

   ```
   root /mnt/www/www.domainname.com;
   index  index.php index.html index.htm;
   ```
2. Create an empty location block *before* all your other location blocks:

   ```
   location /latest {
   # Nothing in here; this is to avoid redirecting for this location
   }
   ```
3. Comment out the root directory directive in your location / {} block and add the redirection so it looks like this:

   ```
   location / {
   # root   /mnt/www/www.domainname.com;
   index  index.php index.html index.htm;
   rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.domainname.com/latest/$1 redirect;
   }
   ```
4. Make sure that your location ~ .php$ block points its root to

   ```
   root /mnt/www/www.domainname.com;
   ```

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

for the just the home page and nothing else, i would use:

```
location / {           
    rewrite ^/$ /blog/ redirect;
}
```

anything else, like /foo/ would not be redirected to /blog/ .