# Redirect root to WordPress subfolder under nginx

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I recently got a VPS with nginx and moved my WordPress instance over. After some browsing around, I got permalinks to work. The blog is located inside a `blog` folder.

I would like for requests to `example.com` to be redirected to `example.com/blog`. However, requests to`example.com/doc/...` should **not** be redirected to `example.com/blog/doc/...`.

I've looked for other questions/answers but they all resulted in an infinite redirect loop.

This is the current config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name mysite.com;

    location / {
            # Redirect to /blog
    }

    location /blog/ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;

    }
}
```

```

Comment: Please edit your question to show your current, non-working configuration. Use the edit and formatting tools to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
location = / {
    return 301 http://example.com/blog;
}
```

The key here is the `=`, which makes nginx apply this rule only to requests arriving to root folder, nowhere else.